# How can i remove default space occupied by label from group?

Tags: java, swt

I want to create a label in one composite and group which contains 2 radio buttons. But I am facing problem while aligning it. It is not properly aligned w.r.t to label. The group has a text or header which I am not using. Due to that text it is not properly aligned. But for composite I am getting the proper behavior and it is aligned properly w.r.t to label. So is there any way to replicate the same thing using group. Below contains the snapshot and code which I used.

Code:

```
shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,false));
GridData grid=new GridData();
Composite comp=new Composite(shell, SWT.None);

comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
Label label = new Label(comp, SWT.None);
label.setText("Invertframe:");

org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group group=new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group(shell, SWT.None);
GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, true);

layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
layout.verticalSpacing = 10;
layout.marginBottom = 0;
layout.marginHeight = 0;
layout.marginWidth = 0;

group.setLayout(layout);

group.setLayoutData(grid);
Button button =new  Button(group, SWT.RADIO);
button.setText("ON");
Button button2 =new  Button(group, SWT.RADIO);
button2.setText("OFF");
comp=new Composite(shell, SWT.None);

comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
label = new Label(comp, SWT.None);
label.setText("Invertframe:");

Composite composite2=new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
layout = new GridLayout(2, true);
composite2.setLayout(layout);
layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
layout.verticalSpacing = 10;
layout.marginBottom = 0;
layout.marginHeight = 0;
layout.marginWidth = 0;

button =new  Button(composite2, SWT.RADIO);
button.setText("ON");
button2 =new  Button(composite2, SWT.RADIO);
button2.setText("OFF");
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just use the `Composite` approach then? If it's just because of the "looks" of the group, then you might be able to create [your own `Widget`](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm) based on `Canvas` to imitate this look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not have tried negative `verticalIndent`

```
protected void createContents()
{
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    GridData grid = new GridData();
    grid.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
    grid.verticalIndent = -6;
    Composite comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.None);

    comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
    Label label = new Label(comp, SWT.None);
    label.setText("Invertframe:");

    org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group group = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group(shell, SWT.None);
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, true);

    layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
    layout.verticalSpacing = 0;
    layout.marginBottom = 0;
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    layout.marginWidth = 0;

    group.setLayout(layout);

    group.setLayoutData(grid);
    Button button = new Button(group, SWT.RADIO);
    GridData gd_button = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1);
    gd_button.verticalIndent = -2;
    button.setLayoutData(gd_button);

    button.setText("ON");
    Button button2 = new Button(group, SWT.RADIO);
    GridData gd_button2 = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1);
    gd_button2.verticalIndent = -2;
    button2.setLayoutData(gd_button2);
    button2.setText("OFF");


    comp = new Composite(shell, SWT.None);

    comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false));
    label = new Label(comp, SWT.None);
    label.setText("Invertframe:");

    Composite composite2 = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    layout = new GridLayout(2, true);
    composite2.setLayout(layout);
    layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
    layout.verticalSpacing = 10;
    layout.marginBottom = 0;
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    layout.marginWidth = 0;

    button = new Button(composite2, SWT.RADIO);
    button.setText("ON");
    button2 = new Button(composite2, SWT.RADIO);
    button2.setText("OFF");
}
```

[image: aligned with Group]

Comment: +1 But keep in mind that setting an exact pixel value will most probably work on one OS, but not the others.

Comment: @Rajesh Make sure you consider Baz comment when running it on any OS other than Windows

Answer (score 0):

Well, you were right. That behaviour is caused by the `Group`'s empty title string. 
I don't think you can get your desired behaviour, but you may want to try applying the following `GridLayout` to your group:

```
final GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) layout;
grid.horizontalSpacing = grid.marginBottom = grid.marginHeight = grid.marginLeft = grid.marginRight = grid.marginTop = grid.marginWidth = grid.verticalSpacing = 0;
```

Comment: That does not change the outcome.

Comment: I noticed he omitted the *marginTop*. Maybe if he fiddles with the `GridData`?

Comment: There might be a way to solve this issue, but please only post answers that you tested yourself or where you know that they work.

Comment: Apparently it's a `Group` limitation. Just use a bordered `Composite` instead of a `Group`.

Comment: But what about curvy look which i get in group

Comment: @Rajesh You could make up for that top margin. Just set lateral and bottom margins to the same one as top, and it will look ok.